# Parse XML result from Web service request Java

Tags: java, xml

I have this XML result from a web service request. The tags that are inside the box are the ones that I need from the xml result.

[image]

Here's what I have so far:

```
private Node getMessageNode(QueryResponseQueryResult paramQueryResponseQueryResult, String[] paramArrayOfString)
  {

MessageElement[] arrayOfMessageElement = paramQueryResponseQueryResult.get_any();
    Document localDocument = null;
    String res;
    try
    {
      localDocument = arrayOfMessageElement[0].getAsDocument(); //result from the webservice
    }
    catch (Exception localException) {}
    if (localDocument == null) {
      return null;
    }
    Object localObject = localDocument.getDocumentElement();
    localObject = Nodes.findChildByTags((Node)localObject, paramArrayOfString);
   return localDocument; //This returns the XML above
  }
```

How do I parse the result to return only those tags on the box and still return it as XML type?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Someone is sending you the XML data with the XML Schema embedded like that? Wow, that's really bad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Xpath of XQuery to perform this task.

You should get the document, and then you can get the child node of table using
[getElementByTagName("table")](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Element.html) or run XPath on it:

See [here](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/java-xml-xpath-tutorial-parse-xml/) a good xpath tutorial.